# Yii CGridView - set default afterAjaxUpdate callback

Tags: php, ajax, yii, cgridview, select-menu

does somebody know a possibilty to set a default function in CGridView, which will run on all grids on the page after every AJAX update?
I use the CGridView on many pages, and I don't want to specify this function for each grid separatly.
I need this because I use [jQuery selectmenu](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui) for my filter dropdowns, and after the AJAX reload, they need to be inicialized again.

```
'afterAjaxUpdate' => "function(id,data){$('select').selectmenu()}";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the format of value http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail

> a javascript function that will be invoked after a successful AJAX response is received. The function signature is function(id, data) where 'id' refers to the ID of the grid view, 'data' the received ajax response data.

You need set

> ```
> 'afterAjaxUpdate' => "function(id,data){$('select').selectmenu()}";
> ```

**UPDATED:**

I don't see another way than create child of `CGridView` and set value of `$afterAjaxUpdate`. Here is the code:

> ```
> class GridView extends CGridView{
>     public $afterAjaxUpdate = "function(id,data){$('select').selectmenu()}";
> }
> ```

**UPDATED:**

I look at the source code of widget and the property `afterAjaxUpdate` used only in the method `registerClientScript`. That's why I propose anothe two solution. First - you may change value of `afterAjaxUpdate` in init of inherited class:

> ```
> public function init(){
>     parent::init(); // after setting all values reset value to desire
>     $this->afterAjaxUpdate = "function(id,data){$('select').selectmenu()}";
>   }
> ```

Second - you can rechange it propery before calling method `registerClientScript`:

> ```
> public function registerClientScript(){
>     $this->afterAjaxUpdate = "function(id,data){$('select').selectmenu()}";
>     parent::registerClientScript();
>   }
> ```

Comment: It's not about the format, I will update my question... This is not the problem. The problem is I need this for every possible GridView, as a default setting

Comment: Hm, this would be a good idea, but then if I need to add some more functionality in one specific grid, then I lose this default function again.. I need the default that way, that it cannot be overriden

Comment: The two suggestions of yours still do the same thing. It does not matter if you set it up in the property, or at init, or even at registerClientScript. Actually this solution will DELETE any other code which normaly may be assigned to in the views that use GridView

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found, that it really is not possible to set a default afterAjaxUpdate function, which would be fired on all grid views automatically.

There however are 2 possiblities, which one can use:

1. See answer from [CreatoR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19770844/1132243) - set the default event in an extended GridView object. This works as long as noone manualy sets an afterAjaxUpdate in a specific grid.
2. You could change (but this is not a real nice "extension" way) the **jquery.yiigridview.js** file to this specific needs, by adding a new option=function, sth like **'***afterAjaxUpdateDefault***'**, and place it before or after the '*afterAjaxUpdate*' is called.